# Can't install on an Asus F5gl laptop

Tags: 11.10, laptop, installation, asus

I downloaded Ubuntu 11.10 and wanted to install it on my Asus f5gl series laptop. (It is around four years old by now).

I created a bootable USB stick installer following the instructions on the Ubuntu page. I can get my laptop to recognize the USB stick, but I can neither boot it nor use it to install.

If I boot the Ubuntu install USB stick, it starts, plays the intro sound and shows the wallpaper and the mouse pointer. But then nothing else happens.

If I try to install then sort of the same thing happens. It starts, does the same thing as before and the install window pops up. But there is no text in the window. I can move the mouse pointer  but I can not click on anything.

Does anyone know what might be wrong? I have searched the web for people with similar problems but so far no luck. Can it be related, somehow, to my laptop specs? Should I install an older version?

**Updated copied from comment:**

I have already tried to install Ubuntu on Windows (with Wubi). The same thing happened. I could only see the wallpaper and the mouse pointer but nothing else.

My disk is a Hitachi HTS542525K9A00. If I go into the BIOS, I only get an option related to SATA to toggle between enhanced and compatible. (I don't recall the name of the option.)

Comment: Your question first says that you can not boot nor install from your USB installer. You then say that when you boot that the desktop (wallpaper) appears. If you see the desktop then, in fact, you **were** able to boot from your USB stick. So why did you say you could not boot from it?

Answer (score 1):

Your HD have ATA and AHCI modes?

Try to change those options in BIOS menu.

- If this option is ATA, then change it to AHCI.
- If this option is AHCI, then change it to ATA.

EDIT:

Try to install Ubuntu with Windows Installer.

After you reinstall using Bootable Pendrive

Comment: i've already tried to install it on Windows (with Wubi). same thing happened. i coould only see the wallpaper and the mouse pointer but nothing else. my disk is an Hitachi HTS542525K9A00. if i go into the BIOS, i only get an option related to SATA to toggle between enhanced and compatible (i don't recall the name of the option).

Comment: First you try Enhanced /

After Compatible

Comment: i've had to put it in compatible mode to install windows xp.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you first try: **Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Lucid)**.

Once that works, then experiment with **11.10 (Oneiric)** and **Unity (3D)**.  These my be too advanced and/or power-hungry for this older netbook.